# Rails 4 with gem route_translator generate too many routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, internationalization

So I gave a shot to the gem route_translator.
The simple reason is that I need it to translate some of my routes in FR and NL.

It works well... a bit "too well" I would say.

route_translator is supposed to take into account my 2 locale files fr.yml and nl.yml

As explained in the doc here https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator, I wrapped the routes I wanted to translate with :

```
localized do
...
end
```

These are my routes:

```
scope '(:locale)', constraints: { locale: /nl|fr/ } do
  devise_for :users

  resources :articles, :path => 'newsfeed', only: [:index, :edit, :destroy, :update, :new, :create]

  localized do
    get 'pages/clients', as: :clients
    get 'pages/employes', as: :employes
  end

  root to: 'languages#select'

  get '*path' => redirect('/')
end
```

My YMLs files are:

For fr.yml

```
fr:
  routes:
    clients: "clients"
    employees: "employes"
```

For nl.yml

```
nl:
  routes:
    clients: "klanten"
    employees: "personeel"
```

As a results I get 52 new routes per translation instead of just 2 (FR and NL).

```
clients_en GET    /en(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"en"}
clients_ar GET    /ar(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"ar"}
clients_az GET    /az(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"az"}
clients_bg GET    /bg(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"bg"}
clients_bn GET    /bn(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"bn"}
clients_bs GET    /bs(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"bs"}
clients_ca GET    /ca(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"ca"}
clients_cs GET    /cs(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"cs"}
clients_da GET    /da(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"da"}
clients_de_ch GET    /de-ch(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"de-CH"}
clients_de GET    /de(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"de"}
clients_el GET    /el(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"el"}
clients_en_gb GET    /en-gb(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"en-GB"}
clients_es_mx GET    /es-mx(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"es-MX"}
clients_es GET    /es(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"es"}
clients_et GET    /et(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"et"}
clients_fa GET    /fa(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"fa"}
clients_fi GET    /fi(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"fi"}
clients_fr_ca GET    /fr-ca(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"fr-CA"}
clients_he GET    /he(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"he"}
clients_hr GET    /hr(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"hr"}
clients_hu GET    /hu(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"hu"}
clients_id GET    /id(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"id"}
clients_is GET    /is(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"is"}
clients_it GET    /it(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"it"}
clients_ja GET    /ja(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"ja"}
clients_ko GET    /ko(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"ko"}
clients_lt GET    /lt(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"lt"}
clients_lv GET    /lv(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"lv"}
clients_my GET    /my(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"my"}
clients_nb GET    /nb(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"nb"}
clients_nl GET    /nl(/:locale)/pages/klanten(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"nl"}
clients_nn_no GET    /nn-no(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"nn-NO"}
clients_no GET    /no(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"no"}
clients_pl GET    /pl(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"pl"}
clients_pt_br GET    /pt-br(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"pt-BR"}
clients_pt GET    /pt(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"pt"}
clients_ro GET    /ro(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"ro"}
clients_ru GET    /ru(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"ru"}
clients_sk GET    /sk(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"sk"}
clients_sl GET    /sl(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"sl"}
clients_sr_rs GET    /sr-rs(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"sr-RS"}
clients_sr GET    /sr(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"sr"}
clients_sv GET    /sv(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"sv"}
clients_th GET    /th(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"th"}
clients_tr GET    /tr(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"tr"}
clients_uk GET    /uk(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"uk"}
clients_vi GET    /vi(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)     pages#clients {:locale=>"vi"}
clients_zh_cn GET    /zh-cn(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"zh-CN"}
clients_zh_hk GET    /zh-hk(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"zh-HK"}
clients_zh_tw GET    /zh-tw(/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)  pages#clients {:locale=>"zh-TW"}
clients_fr GET    (/:locale)/pages/clients(.:format)    pages#clients {:locale=>"fr"}
employes_en GET    /en(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"en"}
employes_ar GET    /ar(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"ar"}
employes_az GET    /az(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"az"}
employes_bg GET    /bg(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"bg"}
employes_bn GET    /bn(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"bn"}
employes_bs GET    /bs(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"bs"}
employes_ca GET    /ca(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"ca"}
employes_cs GET    /cs(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"cs"}
employes_da GET    /da(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"da"}
employes_de_ch GET    /de-ch(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"de-CH"}
employes_de GET    /de(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"de"}
employes_el GET    /el(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"el"}
employes_en_gb GET    /en-gb(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"en-GB"}
employes_es_mx GET    /es-mx(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"es-MX"}
employes_es GET    /es(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"es"}
employes_et GET    /et(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"et"}
employes_fa GET    /fa(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"fa"}
employes_fi GET    /fi(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"fi"}
employes_fr_ca GET    /fr-ca(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"fr-CA"}
employes_he GET    /he(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"he"}
employes_hr GET    /hr(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"hr"}
employes_hu GET    /hu(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"hu"}
employes_id GET    /id(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"id"}
employes_is GET    /is(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"is"}
employes_it GET    /it(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"it"}
employes_ja GET    /ja(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"ja"}
employes_ko GET    /ko(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"ko"}
employes_lt GET    /lt(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"lt"}
employes_lv GET    /lv(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"lv"}
employes_my GET    /my(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"my"}
employes_nb GET    /nb(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"nb"}
employes_nl GET    /nl(/:locale)/pages/personeel(.:format)   pages#employes {:locale=>"nl"}
employes_nn_no GET    /nn-no(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"nn-NO"}
employes_no GET    /no(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"no"}
employes_pl GET    /pl(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"pl"}
employes_pt_br GET    /pt-br(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"pt-BR"}
employes_pt GET    /pt(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"pt"}
employes_ro GET    /ro(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"ro"}
employes_ru GET    /ru(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"ru"}
employes_sk GET    /sk(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"sk"}
employes_sl GET    /sl(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"sl"}
employes_sr_rs GET    /sr-rs(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"sr-RS"}
employes_sr GET    /sr(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"sr"}
employes_sv GET    /sv(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"sv"}
employes_th GET    /th(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"th"}
employes_tr GET    /tr(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"tr"}
employes_uk GET    /uk(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"uk"}
employes_vi GET    /vi(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)    pages#employes {:locale=>"vi"}
employes_zh_cn GET    /zh-cn(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"zh-CN"}
employes_zh_hk GET    /zh-hk(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"zh-HK"}
employes_zh_tw GET    /zh-tw(/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format) pages#employes {:locale=>"zh-TW"}
employes_fr GET    (/:locale)/pages/employes(.:format)       pages#employes {:locale=>"fr"}
```

Just in case, I'm using these gems (they could have a potential impact):
- gem 'devise-i18n'
- gem 'devise'

So here I am. If you have any tips, I'm listening :) (included any alternative to the gem route_translator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
locales = ["nl", "fr"]
locales = Regexp.union(locales)
scope "(:locale)", locale: locales  do
 get 'pages/clients', as: :clients
 get 'pages/employes', as: :employes
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can configure RouteTranslator via an initializer or using the different environment config files.

```
RouteTranslator.config do |config|
  config.force_locale = true
  config.locale_param_key = :my_locale
end
```

> available_locales Use this to limit the locales for which URLs should be generated for. Accepts an array of strings or symbols.

Try adding an `available_locales` option to your config with `[:fr, :nl]`.

Comment: Thanks James. I added `config.i18n.available_locales = [:fr, :nl]` to my application.rb file and it works.